implicit differentiation of $x^{\sqrt{y}}=y^{\sqrt{x}}$
I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to find the tangent to the curve $x^{\sqrt{y}} = y^{\sqrt{x}}$ at the point (1,1).
Here's my attempt:

Starting with $x^{\sqrt{y}} = y^{\sqrt{x}}$

Taking logarithms of both sides: $\sqrt{y}\ln x = \sqrt{x}\ln y$

Squaring both sides: $y\ln^2 x = x\ln^2 y$

Differentiating with respect to $x$ using implicit differentiation:
$y'\ln^2 x + \frac{2\ln x}{x}y = \ln^2 y + 2y'\ln y \cdot x$

Simplifying:
$y'(\ln^2 x - 2x\ln y) = \ln^2 y$

Solving for $y'$:
$y' = \frac{\ln^2 y}{\ln^2 x - 2x\ln y}$

At point (1,1), the last term is not defined.


Question: Could someone point out where I made a mistake in my derivation?

It looks like you forgot $\frac{2\ln x}{x}y$ from step 4 to step 5 - not the real issue, though

At the point $(1,1)$, the curve follows $y = x$. So, $y = x$ is the tangent line to the curve.

@BenGrossmann Can you elaborate?

@ProperIllumination If you graph this equation, you can see that there are two intersecting curves that form the solution set. One of these curves is $y = x$, and the other curve can be parameterized as
$$
\begin{cases}
x = t^{\frac1{1-\sqrt{t}}}\
y = t \cdot t^{\frac{1}{1 - \sqrt{t}}}
\end{cases}, \qquad t > 0.
$$
These curves intersect at the point $(e^2,e^2)$. So, at any point $(x,x)$ with $x > 0$ and $x \neq e^2$, the tangent line is simply $y = x$. At $x = e^2$, there is no well-defined tangent line.

@ProperIllumination ...or from another perspective, there are the two tangent lines $y = x$ and $y = 2e^2 - x$ at $(e^2,e^2)$.

@BenGrossmann how would you proceed without plotting the function?

@DavideMasi In order to prove that the result is correct, it suffices to note that the graph must contain the (points in the first quadrant of) the curve $y = x$ (which does not require graphing). It follows that for any point along $y = x$, if the tangent line to the curve is well-defined, the tangent line must be $y = x$.

In step 2, at $(1,1)$, you have $0 = 0$.  You then perform vacuous operations that accomplish nothing, except Step 5 to 6 involves division by zero.  All these algebraic gymnastics are not helping and many of the operations you are applying are not invertible, meaning if you get a solution it won't pass back to the original equation.

As for your particular problem, we have no need to delve into implicit differentiation. Not only is it harder, but for the point $(1,1)$ in particular it is a nightmare, as we have to take the limit as $x,y\rightarrow1$, since we get a $\frac{0}{0}$ situation. Instead, we should notice that for equalities comparing a two variable function that simply swap the position of the variables, i.e., $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, the line $y=x$ is always a solution if the function is defined there, $f(x,x)=f(x,x)$. Since $(1,1)$ is a point on $y=x$, the tangent line at $(1,1)$ is just $y=x$.
Returning to your implicit differentiation for a moment, your error occurs at step $4$, Where you are missing a division by $y$.

$$x^\sqrt{y}=y^\sqrt{x}\Rightarrow y\ln^2(x)=x\ln^2(y)$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(y\ln^2(x)=x\ln^2(y))\Rightarrow y'\ln^2(x)+\frac{2y\ln(x)}{x}=\ln^2(y)+\frac{2xy'\ln(y)}{y}\space\space\text{ (this y here)}$$
$$y'=\frac{xy\ln^2(y)-2y^2\ln(x)}{xy\ln^2(x)-2x^2\ln(y)}$$
As you can see however, because $\ln(1)=0$ we would needto consider $\lim_{x,y\rightarrow1}{y'}$, which is unnecessarily difficult and annoying.


I liked your observation, thanks a lot.

The logarithmed equation can be rewritten as
$\frac{\ln y}{\sqrt y} = \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x},$
i.e.
$f(y)=f(x),$
where
$f(t) = \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt t}.$
Taking derivative w.r.t. $x$ of both sides of $f(y)=f(x)$ gives
$f'(y)y'=f'(x)$ i.e.
$$
y'=\frac{f'(x)}{f'(y)}
.
$$
At $x=y=c$ we therefore get $y'=1$ unless $f'(c)=0.$
The derivative of $f$ is
$$
f'(t) = \frac{(1/t)\cdot\sqrt t - (\ln t)\cdot1/(2\sqrt t)}{(\sqrt t)^2}
= \frac{2-\ln t}{2t^{3/2}},
$$
which vanishes at $t=e^2$ and diverges at $t=0.$
The solution set actually consists of two graphs, the straight line $x=y$ and a curve looking a bit like a hyperbola. These are colored red in the image. The yellow lines are $x=e^2$ and $y=e^2$.

